# DBUNIT :Verify XML data with Values in DB2 database using DBunit

Tags: xml, database, db2, dbunit

I have a Huge XML with 1000s of records . Our Job loads these items into db2 database. And after that we manually check whether all records made it to the db and all columns are populated as that of XML values.

I heard that DBUnit can simply automate my problem. I tried to copy codes from net and customize. But nothing working fine.

So somebody please provide a samll example to verify XML values against a database.

Thanks in Advance 
WebTester

Answer (score 0):

This working groovy example is designed to demonstrate how to use the dbunit ANT tasks.

To discover the true power of dbunit you need to read the doco and try out the examples:

http://www.dbunit.org/

## Example

Run as follows and discovers an unmatching row of data in the database

```
$ groovy dbunit
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/mark/Files/Dev/groovy/sql/build
   [dbunit] Executing compare: 
   [dbunit]           from file: /home/mark/Files/Dev/groovy/sql/dbunit.xml
   [dbunit]           with format: flat
Caught: : junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: value (table=TEST1, row=2, col=Y) expected:<300[1]> but was:<300[0]>
```

### dbunit.xml

This file contains the expected database data:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
  <TEST1 ID="1" X="10" Y="1000"/>
  <TEST1 ID="2" X="11" Y="2000"/>
  <TEST1 ID="3" X="12" Y="3001"/>
  <TEST1 ID="4" X="13" Y="4000"/>
  <TEST1 ID="5" X="14" Y="5000"/>
  <TEST1 ID="6" X="15" Y="6000"/>
</dataset>
```

### dbunit.groovy

The groovy script creates the H2 database and populates it with data. After which it runs dbunit to make sure the correct data was loaded:

```
//
// Dependencies
// ============
//
import groovy.sql.Sql

@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='com.h2database', module='h2', version='1.3.167'),
    @Grab(group='org.dbunit', module='dbunit', version='2.4.8'),
    @Grab(group='org.slf4j', module='slf4j-simple', version='1.6.4'),
    @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true),
])

//
// Main program
// ============
//
// Connection properties
def driver = "org.h2.Driver"
def url    = "jdbc:h2:build/db/test"
def user   = "user"
def pass   = "pass"

// Cleanup
def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.delete(dir:"build")

// Add the dbunit task into the ANT builder
ant.taskdef(name:"dbunit", classname:"org.dbunit.ant.DbUnitTask")

// Populate the test database
def sql = Sql.newInstance(url, user, pass, driver)
sql.execute("CREATE TABLE test1 (id identity, x varchar(10), y varchar(10))")
sql.execute("INSERT INTO test1 (x,y) VALUES (10,1000)")
sql.execute("INSERT INTO test1 (x,y) VALUES (11,2000)")
sql.execute("INSERT INTO test1 (x,y) VALUES (12,3000)")
sql.execute("INSERT INTO test1 (x,y) VALUES (13,4000)")
sql.execute("INSERT INTO test1 (x,y) VALUES (14,5000)")
sql.execute("INSERT INTO test1 (x,y) VALUES (15,6000)")
sql.close()

// Compare the data
ant.dbunit(driver:driver, url:url, userid:user, password:pass) {
    compare(src:"dbunit.xml", format:"flat")
    dbconfig {
        property(name:"datatypeFactory", value:"org.dbunit.ext.h2.H2DataTypeFactory")
    }
}
```